# Как записать данные из переменной в SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, golang, sqlite3

Я создал базу данных note.db и хочу записать в качестве данных строки из переменных. Но как мне это сделать?

```
import (
"database/sql"
"fmt"
_ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    Date := "12.12.2003"
    Title := "Поездка"
    Body := "Мы должны съездить на природу"

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "note.db")
    defer db.Close()
    _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO note VALUES(Date,Title,Body);") // очевидно это так не работает
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметры:

```golang
_, err = db.Exec(`INSERT INTO note VALUES(?1, ?2, ?3);`, Date, Title, Body)
```

**Ни в коем случае** не стройте
`SQL`-запросы так, как предлагает другой ответ. Это явный
пример
[*SQL*-инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0),
и такого кода нигде быть не должно, особенно
в 2020 году.

Answer (score -1):

Ответ на первый вариант вашего вопроса, Но **так не правильно**

```
"INSERT INTO note VALUES('"+Date+"','"+Title+"','"+Body+"');";
```

Используйте

```
"INSERT INTO note VALUES(?1, ?2, ?3);", Date, Title, Body
```

Comment: Я голосую против этого ответа, потому что это — [*SQL*-инъекция](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/).  Такие практики нельзя использовать, и тем более рекомендовать другим.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @Ainar-G, лучше всегда использовать параметры в подобных случаях. Исправьте пожалуйста ответ. Сюда будут попадать неопытные программисты с поисковиков и, увидев принятый ответ, они могут подумать, что это правильный подход